# Detect clickout within onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search almost the tutorial, tips introduce how to detect a clickout in jQuery. But I think my case is different with almost people. (May be not)

Well, I'm using function to toggle panel for each user on my website. (onclick event)

For example:

With user and his id is 7, so the function to toggle will be : `togglePanel(7);`

It's work fine, no trouble. But when I tried to check if the panel is visible or not (event body click) if yes, then hide it.

=> I can't toggle the panel anymore.

What should I do, please give me some suggestions. Thanks.

By the way, I'm following this tutorial

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var panel = jQuery('.ui-context');
    var link = jQuery('.context-link');
    jQuery(document.body).click(function(){
        if (!panel.has(this).length) {
            panel.hide();
            link.removeClass('context-open');
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the toggle panel function:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
function togglePanel(userId) {
    var lctgLink = "#panel-u" + userId;
    var lctgPanel = "#context-ucp-" + userId;
    jQuery(lctgPanel).toggle();
    jQuery(lctgLink).toggleClass('context-open');
    return false;
}
```

and the html will be:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="panel-u-$uid" onclick="togglePanel($uid);">$username</a>
<div id="context-ucp-$uid" class="ui-context" style="display:none;">
<!-- STUFF HERE -->
</div>
```

Comment: would greatly help to see your html

Comment: @sgroves: Edited. Please re-check